# Unable to get data using requests, no data source in network tab

Tags: python-3.x, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi I am trying to load the https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/ using Requests module and BS4, but I am unable to get the required data. It seems data being loaded using js but I am unable to see any data source in Chrome Dev tools Network tab.

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml
url ='https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

I see that data on site loads on the fly but I don't see any source of that data.
I need to the listings on the site. Not only the basic html which only have script tags

Comment: `I am unable to get the required data`: What is the required data? More context would be good.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need to get to listings that loads, only their URL and title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyppeteer` in combination with `asyncio` to get the listings asynchronously from that site.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = "https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/"

async def get_listings(link):
    wb = await launch({"headless": False})
    [page] = await wb.pages()
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.waitForSelector('#home-rentals')
    containers = await page.querySelectorAll('.rental-item')
    for container in containers:
        title = await container.querySelectorEval('span.caption','e => e.innerText')
        link = await page.evaluate('e => e.href',container)
        print(title,link)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_listings(url))
```

Output are like:

```
VIP SK Drevenica - Liptovská Štiavnica (max. 75) https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/chalupky-u-babky
VIP SK Drevenica - Mýto pod Ďumbierom (max. 28) https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/chata-zinka
VIP SK Drevenica - Liptovský Trnovec (max. 72) https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/liptovske-chaty
VIP SK Drevenica - Ružomberok (max. 90) https://www.ubytovanienaslovensku.eu/chaty-liptovo
```

Comment: Perfect, comprehensive and complete

Answer (score 3):

It's coming from a websocket so you have to search the WS message panel:

[image: WS messages inspector]

You're not going to be able to get that with requests. You could try Selenium.

Comment: Interesting to know +